# Shopify - regular price not showing next to sale price

Tags: php, html, shopify, liquid

if I put a product on sale, on the collections page, there is the crossed out normal price next to the sale price. However, on the product page, the sale price is only shown as if it would be the normal price and the regular price is just loaded for 1 second when you open the product page, and then dissapears. Can someone help please?

```
<div class="product-single__prices">
    {% if product.compare_at_price > product.price %}
      <span id="ComparePriceA11y" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.sale_price' | t }}</span>
    {% else %}
      <span id="PriceA11y" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
    {% endif %}
    <span id="ProductPrice" class="product-single__price" itemprop="price" content="{{ product.price | divided_by: 100.00 }}">
      {{ product.price | money }}
    </span>

    {% if product.compare_at_price > product.price %}
      <span id="PriceA11y" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
      <s id="ComparePrice" class="product-single__sale-price">
        {{ product.compare_at_price_max | money }}
      </s>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
```

Comment: What's the name of the theme you are using?

Comment: Edit the javascript that hides the regular price on the product page.